# No puedo ejecutar los archivos jar directamente

Tags: java, netbeans

Al crear un archivo **jar**, ya sea independiente o en netbeans, no se puede ejecutar directamente y solo funciona con el código de consola.

¿Por qué pasa esto?

---

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas de todas maneras.

Mi sistema operativo es Windows 10, tengo el jre1.8.0_241 y lo instalé de la pagina oficial de Oracle. He recibido comentarios en otros foros haciendo referencia a que no establecí correctamente las variables de entorno, pero en nigun momento pude conseguir la información de como establecerlas correctamente.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Mauricio, bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad y, sobre todo, podamos darte una buena respuesta. ¿Podrías darnos más información de tu sistema operativo (versión de MacOS, distribución de Linux y versión, versión de Windows, FreeBSD, etc)? También nos ayudaría saber qué versión de JRE y qué método de instalación usaste.

Comment: @MaHuerta , no es necesario agregar la etiqueta **netbeans** a la pregunta, éstas deben hacer referencia al problema, no al contenido de la pregunta. Es decir: solo por hacer referencia a netbeans dentro de una pregunta no se le debe agregar dicha etiqueta.

Comment: Una pregunta más al hilo de mi respuesta. ¿Tienes la asociación de archivo tal y como describo en mi respuesta? ¿Qué tipo de aplicación es la que quieres abrir? ¿Dispone de interfaz gráfica o sólo de texto?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando instalas Java SE con el instalador descargado de la página de Oracle, por defecto deberían asociarse los archivos con extensión `.jar` con **Java(TM) Platform SE binary**, pero si se instala posteriormente una aplicación que sea capaz de abrir esos mismos archivos (como 7zip u otros gestores de archivos) y se sobreescribe dicha asociación, se puede recuperar de la siguiente manera:

Pulsamos el botón derecho sobre el archivo `.jar` y hacemos clic en <kbd>Abrir con...</kbd>:

[image: Botón derecho y abrir con...]

Ahora marcamos **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** y la opción **Usar siempre esta aplicación para abrir los archivos .jar**:

[image: Pulsar en "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" y marcar "Usar siempre esta aplicación para abrir los archivos .jar"]

Con esto debería asociarse de nuevo los archivos `.jar` con Java, pero si son aplicaciones de consola no se abrirá ninguna ventana de símbolo de sistema porque por defecto está asociado a `javaw` y no a `java`.

Para agregar la opción de ejecutarlo en un símbolo de sistema deberás crear un archivo de registro (por ejemplo, `java.reg`) que contenga:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar]
@="jarfilelocal"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfilelocal]
@="Executable Jar File Local"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfilelocal\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfilelocal\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfilelocal\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe\" -jar \"%1\" %*"
```

Ten en cuenta que la ruta al archivo `java.exe` en tu máquina puede variar. En este caso se está usando Java SE 7 (`jre7`) una versión de 32 bits en un sistema operativo de 64 bits, por eso la ruta contiene `Program Files (x86)` en vez de `Program Files`.

Para conocer tu ruta puedes usar:

```
C:\Users\Usuario>reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command
  (Predeterminado) REG_SZ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Tras importar el archivo al registro y abrir de nuevo el archivo `.jar` nos solicitará realizar el cambio:

[image: Aceptar el cambio de asociación]

Seleccionando la opción **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** que tiene debajo la marca **Nuevo** y de nuevo activando la opción **Usar siempre esta aplicación para abrir los archivos .jar**, conseguiremos que se abra en una ventana de símbolo de sistema:

[image: Ejecución dentro de una ventana de símbolo de sistema]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, puede ser que lo estés generando mal, o no estes ejecutando el JAR directamente.

La creación de un archivo jar normalmente se hace mediante las opciones de los entornos. En el caso de netbeans te copio el proceso:

> Abre el menú de “Project Properties” (propiedades de proyecto). Haz clic derecho en el nombre del proyecto del cual quieras generar un archivo JAR, y selecciona “properties” (propiedades) en el menú que aparezca.
>
> Marca la casilla que dice “compress JAR file” (comprimir archivo JAR). En tu ventana de propiedades, observa la lista de categorías a la izquierda de la ventana. En la sección de “build” (generar) verás la opción de “packaging” (empaquetando), haz clic en ella. Deberás ver una casilla de “compress JAR file” a la derecha, márcala.
>
> Confirma el cambio. Presiona OK en la esquina inferior derecha.
>
> Genera tu proyecto. Hay varias formas para hacer esto, pero la manera más fácil es presionando el icono que tiene forma de un martillo y está al lado del menú desplegable para ejecutar la configuración.
>
> Ubica el archivo JAR. La ubicación más común en donde estaría el archivo es en Mis Documentos/NetBeansProjects, en Windows, o en la carpeta de Home/NetBeansProjects, en Ubuntu (Linux). En caso de que la carpeta no esté ahí, haz clic en el menú de “Help” (ayuda), selecciona “About” (acerca de) y busca en la sección de “Userdir” (directorio de usuario).
>
> Para ejecutarlo en windows posiblemente puedas hacerlo con doble click. Si no, puedes abrirlo con netbeans u otro entorno o bien abre el símbolo del sistema/terminal y escribe: -java jar "".

Saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. El OP está diciendo que usando instrucciones a través del símbolo de sistema ejecuta correctamente el **jar**, por lo que debemos descartar una mala generación como origen del problema. Es muy probable que sea debido a un problema de integración con el sistema operativo, a lo que no podemos responder porque aún no ha dado datos de él.

Comment: Perfecto! ;) Me dio a entender su pregunta que no conseguía correrlo como JAR fuera del IDE, por lo que entendí que no conseguía empaquetar el JAR correctamente. Siento la pronta respuesta.